# Término para "Aquellos que tienen espadas y saben utilizarlas pero deciden dejarlas envainadas"

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sinónimos

Hace un cuarto de siglo ya, más o menos, me explicaron en clase que en la Biblia hay algunos "problemas de traducción". El ejemplo que me dieron fue que en Lucas 18:25 se dice:

> "Porque es más fácil pasar un **camello** por el ojo de una aguja, que entrar un rico en el reino de Dios"

Y una de las interpretaciones que se hace sobre esta frase es que la palabra aramea "gamla" significaba tanto "soga" como "camello"<sup>1</sup> (y alguién se coló al hacer la traducción).

Hace poco me encontré con otra situación parecida en un video de Internet, en el que se explicaba que en las Bienaventuranzas se dice:

> Bienaventurados los **mansos**, porque ellos poseerán en herencia la tierra.

[Manso](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OG8VjE5%7COGC8HCQ) es, según el DRAE, una persona "de condición benigna y *suave*", pero la connotación de tal adjetivo es como de una persona con carácter **débil**, que no tiene autoridad, que le falta liderazgo e inclusive poco capaz.

Esto se interpreta como que esa "mansedumbre" es humildad, obediencia, rechazo a la violencia, etc. (y por eso los *mansos* son bienaventurados).

El tertuliano del video en cuestión (cierto profesor de psicología canadiense) decía que, al igual que pasa con el ejemplo del  camello y la aguja, la palabra `manso` tenía otras connotaciones cuando el texto fue redactado, algo que vendría a significar

> Aquellos que tienen espadas y saben cómo utilizarlas, pero que prefieren dejarlas envainadas.

Es decir, "aquellos que tienen capacidad e incluso habilidad para ejercer la violencia, pero deciden no hacerlo porque tienen bajo control esa capacidad para hacer daño". Como un tipo que fuese cinturón negro de artes marciales pero que para resolver un conflicto intentase usar la violencia como último recurso, a pesar de ser más que competente en ella, en lugar de ir a lo "fácil" de imponerse a base de golpes.

Lo que le da un significado completamente distinto a esa Bienaventuranza, claro.

El tema de conversación en el vídeo era que hay una diferencia entre no tener capacidad (posibilidad, fuerza, oportunidad) para hacer el mal y ser capaz pero *elegir* no hacerlo (una persona buena es aquella que *puede* resultar peligrosa, pero tiene ese aspecto de su personalidad bajo completo control).

Me he enrollado un poco, pero me apetecía contar y explicar la anécdota.

¿Hay algún término en español que recoja mejor ese sentido de "Aquellos que tienen espadas y saben utilizarlas pero deciden dejarlas envainadas"? Es decir un término para "aquellos que aún teniendo capacidad y competencia para ejercer la violencia deciden no hacerlo".

---

<sub>1. Esta es una de las "teorías" que hay sobre la interpretación de esta frase, junto a la literal (lo absurdo de que este animal pudiese pasar por el ojo de una aguja) y que "ojo de una aguja" es una referencia a una puerta pequeña.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Probablemente, `indulgente` o `clemente` podrían ser palabras que describen, de mejor manera, a alguien que —teniendo la capacidad de actuar— moderan su respuesta o, incluso, perdonan y deciden no actuar (no he podido pensar en una que, en su definición, se tome en cuenta el aspecto violento o dañino). Aquí te dejo las definiciones del DLE:

> **Indulgente**: 1. adj. Inclinado a perdonar y disimular los yerros o a conceder gracias.
>
> **Clemente**: 1. adj. Que tiene clemencia (Compasión, moderación al aplicar justicia).

También pensé en `misericordioso`, pero creo que la definición del DLE dista bastante de lo que preguntas:

> **Misericordioso:** 1. adj. Que se conduele de los trabajos y miserias ajenos. U. t. c. s.

Curiosamente, su equivalente en inglés (*merciful*), definido por el Cambridge English Dictionarry, se acerca bastante a la palabra que buscas (y, desafortunadamente, no he podido encontrar una con una definición similar en DLE):

> **merciful:** someone who [...] is willing to be kind to and forgive people who are in their power:

Nótese cómo, en esa definición, es explícito que aquel que perdona está en una posición de poder sobre el perdonado.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción puede ser:

> **[Templanza](https://www.google.com/search?q=templanza&oq=templanza&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1871j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**: Cualidad humana que induce a usar o hacer las cosas con
>   moderación.

Una definición que me parece adecuada de compartir proviene de esta [fuente](https://definicion.de/templanza/):

> La templanza permite que la persona sea equilibrada y **sopese su
>   tendencia natural** hacia los placeres de los sentidos y el recogimiento
>   espiritual.

Comment: Buena contribución, pero la templanza es una virtud. Cómo llamamos a aquellos que exhiben la cualidad de la templanza?

Comment: @Diego [temple](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/temple): Capacidad de una persona para enfrentarse con serenidad a situaciones difíciles o peligrosas. También puede ser *moderado*.