# ¿Erratas en la traducción española de la Biblia?

Tags: ortografía, escritura

Por ejemplo, las lecturas diarias para el [cinco de mayo de 2020](http://usccb.org/bible/lecturas/050520.cfm) tiene erratas en el salmo responsorial como "todas los pueblos" y "Jerusalén, cuidad del Señor." ¿O acaso no son errores? Supuestamente viene del leccionario usado en México.

Comment: Sería de ayuda que copiaras aquí los textos que consideras más traducidos, así como cuál crees que sería la traducción correcta.

Comment: No entiendo bien cuál es tu pregunta exactamente y cómo podemos ayudarte. ¿Hay erratas en esa traducción de la biblia? Sí pero ¿qué tiene que ver exactamente eso con el lenguaje español? Hay erratas en casi todos los libros en cualquier idioma.

Comment: No sé de qué traducción es. Al Googlear el verso, el único resultado fue de ese sitio de web. No obstante, cualquier traducción legítima no tendría tantos errores, y son tantos.

Comment: En la Biblia no hay "erratas" (ni fallos de imprenta), hay "problemas de traducción" (el matiz es un poco distinto). Yo lo mencioné de pasada en [Término para “Aquellos que tienen espadas y saben utilizarlas pero deciden dejarlas envainadas”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28733/5481). Otra cosa es que algunas ediciones o versiones, como cualquier libro, tengan erratas o fallos de edición.

Comment: @Diego Los veo más como fallos de imprenta, no como problemas de traducción. Es muy difícil traducir "city" (o lo que sea en hebreo) como "cuidad." No obstante, es bastante fácil escribir "ciudad" como "cuidad" sin cuidado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confieso no entender que quiere decir la pregunta con "la traducción española de la Biblia", porque en realidad son varias. Entre ellas están la Reina Valera, la Biblia de las Américas, y otras. Dicho eso, no he podido encontrar estas frases en ninguna de ellas.

Obviamente, "cuidad del Señor", un imperativo sin sentido, y "ciudad del señor", una frase nominal, no son lo mismo. Tampoco tiene sentido "todas los pueblos", ya que el sustantivo y el adjetivo no concuerdan.

Parece que se trata de un simple error. La transposición de dos letras es facilísima; asimismo, escribir "a" en vez de "o" es inevitable con la ayuda de los correctores automáticos de texto.

Comment: Sea lo que sea la traducción, los traductores no debían hecho tantos errores, y son muchos. Pero, no son errores que podría producir Google Translate. También me sorprendería si contrataran a un gringo para hacer la traducción.